# Conditionally display an image in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting, google-query-language

I have a column of checkboxes and when I query this column it returns TRUE/FALSE. Could I display something other than TRUE/FALSE using conditional formatting? i.e. an image of a checkmark or 'X'

An alternative idea:

Use a helper column along with an if statement to display what I'd like, and query that helper column instead. Would the character/image be processed by query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value of the checkbox by default is TRUE/FALSE but it can be custom:

[image]

formulas are not permitted as custom ticked/unticked values:

[image]

with the conditional formatting you can only paint the background of the checkbox or the checkbox itself to a color of your wish

[image]

QUERY is not able to read images:

[image]

you can use FILTER:

[image]

to assign image you can use VLOOKUP:

```
=FILTER({IFNA(VLOOKUP(A15:A18, G15:H, 2, 0)), B15:B18}, A15:A18="yes")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, these are all good. I ended up going with using characters instead of images as it looks like query can display those without any issues.